# Авторизация Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Есть кнопка "Личный кабинет", при нажатии на которую открывается форма авторизации. Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь уже автортзован, то по этой же кнопке он сразу переходил в личный кабинет?

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавить условие в контроллер. Код приведите контроллера который отвечает за роут.

Comment: Да я даже и не знаю, где это. Ларавел же всё автоматом создал.

Comment: Так посмотрите маршруты `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Много всего вывелось, добавил код, не знаю то ли это вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Наоборот. Делаешь переход в личный кабинет. А если пользователь не авторизован, то запускаешь авторизацию.

Если у тебя есть вот такой маршрут:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
```

И вот такая кнопка:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile') }}">Личный кабинет</a>
```

То тебе осталось указать используемого посредника (middleware) - `auth`. Посредника можно указать либо в конструкторе контроллера (в моём примере это ProfileController):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

либо прямо в маршруте:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('profile');
```

Comment: У меня сейчас кнопка "Личный кабинет" прописана через button и открывает не отдельную страницу, а форму авторизации поверх уже открытой другой страницы. Я думал вообще полностью кнопку поменять (когда авторизован) и чтобы она была через <a>  с ссылкой на страницу личного кабинета.

Comment: Ты спрашиваешь одно, а на деле другое. Если у тебя "форму авторизации поверх уже открытой другой страницы", то, скорее всего, тебе надо править вьюху, чтобы эта "форма авторизации" была скрыта. Или у тебя кнопка отрабатывает на стороне клиента? Тогда тебе надо править java-скрипты. Покажи свою реализацию.